# Java BufferedWriter Precision for Entire File

Tags: java, file, output, precision, bufferedwriter

Say I have:

```
double num = 893.148723
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(filePath)));
bw.write(String.format("%.1f",num));
```

This will write 893.1 to the file. However, is there a way to set the precision for the entire file? I will be outputting a ton of numbers and shouldn't have to code the String.format() part every time I write a number.

Comment: Someone has to format the number if you want only one digit precision. And you have no choice but format each individual number before writing it.

Comment: What about overriding the Double.toString() method?

Comment: You can't. It's public final class Double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if there is no such built-in option you can create your own class extending `BufferedWriter`

```
public class BufferedWriterWithFormat extends BufferedWriter {
    private String format;

    public BufferedWriterWithFormat(Writer w, String format) {
        super(w);
        this.format = format;
    }

    public void write(double d) throws IOException {
        write(String.format(format, d));
    }
}
```